# Can we move a source from one collector to another in Sumo Logic

Tags: sumologic

we have two sumo logic collectors one for QA & the other for Prod.

And we had to create a source for an application in both of there collectors. However, by mistake we created both of them in the same collector (QA).

Now, I want to move the prod source from the QA collector to actual prod collector. Is it possible to achieve this or should I create a new one in prod collector and delete the old one in QA collector?